# geometry nodes: how to assign an image texture to a geometry

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry-nodes

if i create an image texture node, the output is a color. what do i do with that?

i cannot figure out where i should use this as an input.

online i have only found more complicated methods where an image is used as a base for the point distribution. however, i want to apply it to an object.

i think i understand how the UV Unwrap nodes works with the image texture mode, but i don't know what next to do.

does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Hello ! You can't assign an image texture to a geometry (unless you want to bake it to vertex colors, which I assume you don't ?). An Image texture, while containing rasterized data, or pixels, is way too dense to be 1-1 associated with geometry. What you want to do is to assign a UV map which is then used by the *material* to display the image texture. The renderer will interpolate between the UV coordinates of your vertices to display the image correctly on the polygons.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you want to do? There seems to be a misunderstanding here. As @Gorgious correctly pointed out, you never use an Image Texture in Geometry Nodes to texture an object, but only to influence the positions of the geometry with its color values (or similar).